# In R: How do I turn factors into columns AND populate those columns with their corresponding values from another column?

Tags: r, dataframe, reshape

I have a data.frame organized like so:

```
   id question input
1  11        1     6
2  12        1     7
3  13        1     5
4  14        2     5
5  15        2     6
6  16        3     4
7  17        4     5
8  18        4     5
9  19        4     4
10 20        5     3
```

I need to turn the column "question" into a series of columns (one for question 1, one for question 2, etc.), which is OK - I've found the answer to that online.

However, I also need to populate these new columns with the corresponding values from 'input', so the resulting data.frame looks like this:

```
   id question input q1 q2 q3 q4 q5
1  11        1     6  6 NA NA NA NA
2  12        1     7  7 NA NA NA NA
3  13        1     5  5 NA NA NA NA
4  14        2     5 NA  5 NA NA NA
5  15        2     6 NA  6 NA NA NA
6  16        3     4 NA NA  4 NA NA
7  17        4     5 NA NA NA  5 NA
8  18        4     5 NA NA NA  5 NA
9  19        4     4 NA NA NA  4 NA
10 30        5     3 NA NA NA NA  3
```

How would I go about reshaping the data like this, from start to finish? I'm still very much a beginner and would appreciate any help!

Answer (score 5):

You can use `dcast` from the "reshape2" package, like this:

```
dcast(mydf, id + question + input ~ question, value.var = "input")
#    id question input  1  2  3  4  5
# 1  11        1     6  6 NA NA NA NA
# 2  12        1     7  7 NA NA NA NA
# 3  13        1     5  5 NA NA NA NA
# 4  14        2     5 NA  5 NA NA NA
# 5  15        2     6 NA  6 NA NA NA
# 6  16        3     4 NA NA  4 NA NA
# 7  17        4     5 NA NA NA  5 NA
# 8  18        4     5 NA NA NA  5 NA
# 9  19        4     4 NA NA NA  4 NA
# 10 20        5     3 NA NA NA NA  3
```

Answer (score 4):

if `dat` is the dataset

```
fun1 <- function(data){
 m1 <- matrix(ncol=length(unique(data$question)), nrow=nrow(data))
 m1[cbind(1:nrow(data), data$question)] <- data$input
 res <- cbind(data, m1)
 colnames(res)[-(1:3)] <- paste0("q", colnames(res)[-(1:3)])
 res
 }

 fun1(dat) 
#   id question input q1 q2 q3 q4 q5
#1  11        1     6  6 NA NA NA NA
#2  12        1     7  7 NA NA NA NA
#3  13        1     5  5 NA NA NA NA
#4  14        2     5 NA  5 NA NA NA
#5  15        2     6 NA  6 NA NA NA
#6  16        3     4 NA NA  4 NA NA
#7  17        4     5 NA NA NA  5 NA
#8  18        4     5 NA NA NA  5 NA
#9  19        4     4 NA NA NA  4 NA
#10 20        5     3 NA NA NA NA  3
```

Or using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
dat %>% 
mutate(question1=question) %>%
spread(question1, input)
```

Comment: +1. Was *just* about to update my answer with almost the same thing. Good old matrix indexing....

Comment: @Ananda Mahto. I didn't think about `dcast`.  Yours is more elegant, though. +1

Comment: I actually disagree. Yours essentially boils down to a pretty simple but hugely efficient operation. I guess it depends on [what is meant by elegant code](http://news.mrdwab.com/2012/12/04/what-exactly-is-elegant-code-in-r/).... Wrap your approach in a function and it can instantly look cleaner :-)